# Kendo Grid - its own Loading indicator

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, loading, indicator

Kendo grid provides its own Loading indicator automatically when the grid is loaded, paging, sorting. It is working fine.

But I don't  want this built-in loading indicator to be shown/hidden.

How can I disable this feature?

Please advise me.

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 12):

Simple, just hide it with CSS. Your selector will need to be more specific than the built-in Kendo classes. You can use the Grid's ID for that.

```
#grid .k-loading-image {
    background-image: none;
}
```

If you want to remove the loading mask you can also accomplish that with CSS.

```
#grid .k-loading-color {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey nukefusion,   Thanks for your answer. The above code will only make backgroud image as none but it will show mask. My question is I dont want whole k-loading  class. Where to put this code $('#mygrid').removeClass('.k-loading')? whether in grid databound or request start or jquery document.ready.. Please help me..

Comment: If you don't want the mask you can also hide that with CSS, you don't need to resort to javascript modifications. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I had two grids named "grid1" and "grid2" - each was enclosed within a div; named "grid1panel" and "grid2panel". To remove the spinner/wait cursor I added an override for the the grid panels ".k-loading-image" and ".k-loading-color"; this removed it just for these specific grids.

## Sample CSS

```
/* DISABLE KENDO SPINNER/WAIT CURSOR */
.grid1panel .k-loading-image {
    background-image: none;
}
.grid1panel .k-loading-color {
    opacity: 0;
}
.grid2panel .k-loading-image {
    background-image: none;
}
.grid2panel .k-loading-color {
    opacity: 0;
}
```