# How to turn off ajax global setting during kendo grid's ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In MVC 5 in _layout page i have .ajaxStart & .ajaxStop event to show the busy indicator.

```
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ajaxStart(function (e) {            
           $("#loading-div-background");

           $("#loading-div-background").show();
        });

        $(document).ajaxStop(function (e) {

            $("#loading-div-background").hide();
        });
   </script>
</body>
```

We are using kendo grid which makes the ajax request to populate the grid. Kendo has its own busy indicator. We would like to use kendo's busy indicator and turn off the gloabal indicator in certain cases.  Usually we can turn off the global by setting the global to false when we make ajax call.

$.ajax({
            global: false
        })

However with kendo, we are not explicitly making the ajax call How do i set global to false here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428018/kendo-grid-its-own-loading-indicator

Comment: @Hackerman that is not my question. Right now i see both the busy indicator. Our own and also kendo's indicator. I want to turn off the global ajax settings so it wont show our own indicator.

Comment: It's a workaround....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");    
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.global = false;
```

Comment: Good one. Where did you found this ? can you explain how it's works

Comment: as per kendo documentation datasource has read as method and i guess there is also read property which passes all the information to undernethe ajax call http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-read

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try for tricky.  You can use one global variable and use it as flag in your ajaxStart method.
Find suitable event from  ["http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events"](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events)

On this event set your globle variable value to false.

FOR EXAMPLE :

```
var flag = true;
 function onDataBinding(arg) {
                   flag = false;
                }

$(document).ajaxStart(function (e) {
if(flag){$("#loading-div-background").show();}

        });
```

Make sure to maintain flag value in grid events.

Comment: Hooking a grid event is the way to go. Like @Kaushik said use .DataBinding("onDataBinding").